# Where do I put files to be read by java.io.FileReader?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm using java.io.FileReader:

```
FileReader fileReader =  = new FileReader(filepath)
```

When running locally, a typical filepath would be
"/Users/acypher/Desktop/enrollment.json"

Then, when I deploy to Tomcat on AWS, I want to put the file somewhere in the build that FileReader can find -- any place is fine with me, but I haven't been able to find any location that works, since I don't know what root directory FileReader is using.

The .war expands to a folder which includes META-INF and WEB-INF subfolders. WEB-INF contains a "classes" folder, which contains files that are locally in my src/main/resources/ folder, so that seems like a good location. But I don't know how to set the filepath to refer to this location.

I'm using IDEA with Spring Boot.

Comment: If the files are in the WAR file you dont use `FileReader`, you use `Classloader.getResource()` and friends.

Comment: Thanks. I think this means that I'm going about my problem the wrong way. Instead, I'm going to just do a File Upload from the user's machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/src/main/resources/` is definitely the way to go. You can access the files in this folder with the methods `Class.getResource(String)` or `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

For example, if you have your file in `/src/main/resources/myFolder/myFile.myExt`, you can either call:

1. `this.getClass().getResource("myFolder/myFile.myExt")`
2. `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myFilder/myFile.myExt")`

which, in a static context, where you don't have the `this` reference, become, respectively:

1. `MyClass.class.getResource...`
2. `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream`

In the first case you *should* (I didn't verify it myself) be able to create a `File` instance like this: `File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("myFolder/myFile.myExt").toURI())`, and from that the `FileReader` instance; while in the second case, you have at your disposal the `InputStream` which you can use to read the file.